# what does "Warning: This function only accepts a single "bytes" argument. Please use "abi.encodePacked(...)" mean

Tags: solidity, abi

In [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50551/solidity-how-to-get-a-bytes32-keccak256-hash-of-an-address-and-2-uint256-variab) question the OP is running into a warning upon using the `keccak256` function in Solidity:

> Warning: This function only accepts a single "bytes" argument. Please use "abi.encodePacked(...)" or a similar function to encode the data.

```
uint256 _unixTimestamp;
uint256 _timeExpired;

bytes32 output = keccak256(msg.sender, _unixTimestamp, _timeExpired);
```

What is the rationale behind this error - why do I need to use `abi.encodePacked` and what does it do in comparison to using it just like shown above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to Solidity 0.5.0, both functioned the same way. The warning is part of the process of deprecating the variable-argument versions of `keccak256` and other hash functions.

As of Solidity 0.5.0, `sha3` has been removed. See https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3955 for details.

Answer (score 24):

It means that now you need to change your code to:

```
uint256 _unixTimestamp;
uint256 _timeExpired;

bytes32 output = keccak256(
  abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, _unixTimestamp, _timeExpired)
);
```